# Image onload call on an object property

Tags: javascript, image, object, preload

I have a problem calling the onload() function of a new image object when that image is immediately set as an object property. My parser tells me that imageMap[featureId].onload is not a function. I don't get why the imageMap[featureId] isn't synonymous with the image itself? The resourceList is used as an argument to preloadResource(). I have a setinterval elsewhere waiting for the loaded count to equal the resource count. Any ideas please?

```
 var resourceList = ["path.png","path.png","path.png","path.png"];
 var loadedResource = 0;


 function preloadResource(resArr)
 {
            var buildIndex = 1;         

                for (i = 1; i <= resArr.length; i++) 
                {
                    var featureId = "feature" + buildIndex;
                    imageMap[featureId] = new Image();
                    imageMap[featureId].path = resArr[(i - 1)];
                    buildIndex++;
                    imageMap[featureId].onload(function () {loadedResource++;})
                    imageMap[featureId].src = resArr[(i -1)];               
                }
}
```

Comment: _“I have a setinterval elsewhere waiting for the loaded count to equal the resource count”_ – that is a rather bad implementation already. Instead, you should handle that inside your onload callback function – make it increase the counter for each loaded image, and then have it check if the counter reached the target, and if so trigger whatever you want to be done then.

Comment: And the error is because you are _using_ onload like a function, with `imageMap[featureId].onload(…)` – that is a function call, that tries to execute the function `imageMap[featureId].onload`. _Assigning_ a handler function to onload works via `.onload = function …`

Comment: Hi CBroe, yes thats the problem thanks. Also right about the check INSIDE of the onload. Thats faster and more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you the problem: "onload is not a method."

```
imageMap[featureId].onload = function () {loadedResource++;};
```

or use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)